# PIL: How to make area transparent in PNG?

Tags: python, image, png, transparency, python-imaging-library

I've been using PIL to crop Images, now I also want to make certain rectangular areas transparent, say

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("sample.png")
transparent_area = (50,80,100,200)
...
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
im = Image.open("image.png")
transparent_area = (50,80,100,200)

mask=Image.new('L', im.size, color=255)
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
draw.rectangle(transparent_area, fill=0)
im.putalpha(mask)
im.save('/tmp/output.png')
```

I learned how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circuar-thumbnails-with-pil).

Comment: Upvoted you because the code follows pretty much exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Indeed, @kindall, our answers are pretty much identical! :)

Answer (score 4):

No source code, but this is the general approach that should work: Create an alpha channel for the image in "L" (grayscale) mode as a separate image object. Fill the alpha channel with white (full opacity) and draw the rectangle on the alpha channel image in black (full transparency). Convert the image to which you want to apply the transparency to RGBA and use the image object `putalpha()` method to copy the alpha channel you created into the image's alpha channel. Save as PNG.