# Problems with transparent overlapping image in openCv

Tags: python, opencv, graphics, computer-vision

I have issue where I have transparent part of image, but I am not sure if it really is transparent because I can not see what is behind transparent part and it is look like there is nothing but under it should be another image, problem looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5AAX.png) or [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAIlQ.png). If I do not use masks for deleting black edges [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArYIE.png)

I want to make edges completely transparent or entirely delete them.

Thank you for your help. Have a nice day

## this is how I load image

```
    trainImg = cv2.imread(fnames[x], cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    trainImg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(trainImg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    queryImg = cv2.imread(fnames[y], cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    queryImg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(queryImg, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

## this is how I work with pictures

```
        height = trainImg.shape[0] + queryImg.shape[0]
        width = trainImg.shape[1] + queryImg.shape[1]
        dim = (trainImg.shape[1], trainImg.shape[0])
        print(fnames_cropped[x])

        trainImg = cv2.imread(fnames_cropped[x])
        (b, g, r) = cv2.split(trainImg)
        trainImg = cv2.merge([r, g, b])
        trainImg = cv2.resize(trainImg, dim)

        trainImg = trim(trainImg)

        dim = (queryImg.shape[1], queryImg.shape[0])
        print(fnames_cropped[y])
        queryImg = cv2.imread(fnames_cropped[y])
        (b, g, r) = cv2.split(queryImg)
        queryImg = cv2.merge([r, g, b])

        queryImg = cv2.resize(queryImg, dim)

        queryImg = trim(queryImg)

        # Make mask of black pixels - mask is True where image is black
        RGB = np.array(trainImg)
        h, w = RGB.shape[:2]

        # Add an alpha channel, fully opaque (255)
        RGBA = np.dstack((RGB, np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.uint8) + 255))

        # Make mask of black pixels - mask is True where image is black
        mBlack = (RGBA[:, :, 0:3] == [0, 0, 0]).all(2)

        # Make all pixels matched by mask into transparent ones
        RGBA[mBlack] = (0, 0, 0, 0)

        trainImg = RGBA

        # Make mask of black pixels - mask is True where image is black
        RGB = np.array(queryImg)
        h, w = RGB.shape[:2]

        # Add an alpha channel, fully opaque (255)
        RGBA = np.dstack((RGB, np.zeros((h, w), dtype=np.uint8) + 255))

        # Make mask of black pixels - mask is True where image is black
        mBlack = (RGBA[:, :, 0:3] == [0, 0, 0]).all(2)

        # Make all pixels matched by mask into transparent ones
        RGBA[mBlack] = (0, 0, 0, 0)

        queryImg = RGBA

        result = cv2.warpPerspective(trainImg, H, (width, height), flags=cv2.INTER_NEAREST, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

        im = Image.fromarray(trim(result))


        result[0:queryImg.shape[0], 0:queryImg.shape[1]] = queryImg

        im = Image.fromarray(trim(result))
        im.save(feature_extractor+feature_matching+fnames_cropped[x]+fnames_cropped[y])
```

Comment: the image will be a rectangle, right. How do you want to represent nonimportant part of the image

Comment: It should be again transparent, because I will be adding another images to those stitched images.

Comment: try to save image as png.

Comment: I am saving it in PNG :/

Comment: go through im.save function https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save
then different format an image can be saved https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html

Comment: im.save(feature_extractor+feature_matching+fnames_cropped[x]+fnames_cropped[y], format="PNG")
still same result :/

Comment: Please check the below links....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379978/python-pil-how-to-make-area-transparent-in-png
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio