# How to convert a numpy.ndarray frame into a ImageBitmap / VideoFrame for canvas

Tags: javascript, python, canvas

I am using Python opencv in order to process video frames and do some manipulation on them like resizing, cropping etc., but before I resize them, I needed some effects that I could only find in node canvas API, so after researching for so long I came across this library that could help use javascript library/code in python, i.e. `pip install javascript`

```py
import javascript
libcanvas = javascript.require("canvas")
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')

canvas = libcanvas.createCanvas(width, height)
context = canvas.getContext("2d")

def generate_frame():
        while cap.isOpened():
            code, frame = cap.read()
            if code:
                yield frame
            else:
                print("done")
                break
for i, frame in enumerate(generate_frame()):
       context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(frame, "no-repeat")
```

In the above code, I first setup a canvas element and its context and when I try input the frame extracted from opencv into the canvas drawImage or createPatter, I got the following errors:-

```
[JSE] FATAL ERROR: v8::ToLocalChecked Empty MaybeLocal.
```

[image]

[image]

What is wrong with the above code? and is this the right way of achieving this?

Comment: you should be asking how to replicate those "effects", rather than complicate your setup

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I tried that using PIL, I wanted to render another image on top of a background and have rounded corners to the overlay image, but PIL doesn't give perfect rounded corners, they look rough and not smooth like we get in canvas. I also need to add shadows, a transparent outline on the overlayed image.
For example, in this you can see that the final rounded image has rough corners :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287402/how-to-round-corner-a-logo-without-white-backgroundtransparent-on-it-using-pi

Comment: that's because the author of the top rated answer simply used binary masks their their stuff. to get smooth edges, use alpha-blending. -- if you want css-like composition and styling, you should indeed stick to html/css/js. or find a drawing library that can do it, like cairo (or AGG/aggdraw)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, I tried using cairo, but it didn't have features like shadow, shadow blur, blurring the background, blend mode luminosity, adding transparent outline etc.