# How Can I Apply Custom Corner Radius to an Image Inside a CTkFrame Using customtkinter in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm currently working on a Python project using `customtkinter`, and I'm facing an issue with applying a custom corner radius to an image inside a `CTkFrame`. Here's a minimal example of my code:

```py
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image

image_path = #image path

class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=200, height=111, corner_radius=5)
        frame.pack()

        image = customtkinter.CTkImage(Image.open(image_path), size=(200, 111))

        image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame, image=image, text="")
        image_label.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

In this code, I'm trying to display an image inside a `CTkFrame` with a custom corner radius. However, the image doesn't follow the corner radius of the parent frame and appears with sharp corners.

I attempted to use a canvas to mask the image with rounded corners, but this approach results in low resolution corners and the corners don't always match the background.

How can I properly apply the custom corner radius to the image inside the `CTkFrame`?

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I searched for a bit in the documentation and read some parts of the CTkImage and CTkFrame code but didn't found anything. There might be a way to do it using the tkinter Canvas widget but it seems very complicated for what you are trying to do.
The easiest solution is probably to use images with already rounded corners and not trying to round them using customtkinter.

Answer (score 0):

I was scrolling on stackoverflow and found this post: [how to round_corner a logo without white background(transparent?) on it using pil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287402/how-to-round-corner-a-logo-without-white-backgroundtransparent-on-it-using-pi)

It reminded me of your question I commented on 4 days ago saying it is not possible to round corners in customtkinter, so I am here to correct myself.

It is indeed possible to do it using `PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.ellipse()`, here is the code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def add_corners(im, rad):
    circle = Image.new('L', (rad * 2, rad * 2), 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle)
    draw.ellipse((0, 0, rad * 2 - 1, rad * 2 - 1), fill=255)
    alpha = Image.new('L', im.size, 255)
    w, h = im.size
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, 0, rad, rad)), (0, 0))
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, rad, rad, rad * 2)), (0, h - rad))
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, 0, rad * 2, rad)), (w - rad, 0))
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, rad, rad * 2, rad * 2)), (w - rad, h - rad))
    im.putalpha(alpha)
    return im
```

In you case, the full code is:

```py
import customtkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

image_path = #image path


def add_corners(im, rad):
    circle = Image.new('L', (rad * 2, rad * 2), 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(circle)
    draw.ellipse((0, 0, rad * 2 - 1, rad * 2 - 1), fill=255)
    alpha = Image.new('L', im.size, 255)
    w, h = im.size
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, 0, rad, rad)), (0, 0))
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((0, rad, rad, rad * 2)), (0, h - rad))
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, 0, rad * 2, rad)), (w - rad, 0))
    alpha.paste(circle.crop((rad, rad, rad * 2, rad * 2)), (w - rad, h - rad))
    im.putalpha(alpha)
    return im


class App(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=200, height=111, corner_radius=5)
        frame.pack()

        image = customtkinter.CTkImage(add_corners(Image.open(image_path), 100), size=(200, 111))

        image_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(frame, image=image, text="")
        image_label.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

But this only works using .png pictures if you want a transparent background (like said in the post linked above).

If you have more questions, you should refere to the post above: there is already troubleshooting here.

Hope I helped you, have a nice day.

Edit: because I found rounding corners useful, I created a module containing a class to automate this functionnality, the module is called MoreCustomTkinterWidgets on Pypi.