# Is there an antialiasing method for Python PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, antialiasing

For lines and ellipses in PIL, the images are rough.

I found antialiasing only in resize and thumbnail.

Is there any way to do antialiasing when drawing a line or ellipse?

Comment: You could do a low-pass filtering :) You will probably want to move to `aggdraw` (or `cairo`, or ...) for "fancier" drawing.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The only way to do it natively is with supersampling. Render your image at a multiple of the size you require, then [`resize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) it with `resample=Image.LANCZOS`, e.g.:

```py
im = im.resize((width // 2, height // 2), resample=Image.LANCZOS)
```

If you have a very old version of PIL (before Pillow 2.7.0) you need to use `ANTIALIAS` instead of `LANCZOS`.  The `ANTIALIAS` constant which was originally recommended with this answer has been deprecated for years, and was finally removed in Pillow 10.0.

Comment: @Hugo:  In the [`Image.resize()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) method of the current stable version of  the pillow fork of `PIL`, the keyword argument is named `resample`. This may have been changed in [version 2.7.0](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/2.7.0.html?highlight=ANTIALIAS#image-resizing-filters). Also note that `Image.LANCZOS` [is the same thing](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html?highlight=ANTIALIAS) as `Image.ANTIALIAS`—which isn't mentioned in the method's documentation.

Comment: `img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)` works for me. Thank you !

Comment: I was having this issue with an ellipse mask and following answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22336005/1092815

Same answer, but with complete code example

Comment: This is great. Note that  3 times multiplier gives much better results than 2 times, and I felt actually better than 4 times.

Comment: PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS nowadays (Pillow 9.2.0)

Comment: @Conor you don't need the `PIL.` part if you've imported `Image` directly as I often do.  And there are more changes afoot, I've just updated the answer and I'll probably have to do it again soon as the constants were moved from `Image.` to `Image.Resampling.`  My best research indicates that the `Image` constants were deprecated as of Pillow 9.1.

Answer (score 6):

aggdraw (http://effbot.org/zone/aggdraw-index.htm) may be something you're interested in.

The aggdraw module implements the basic WCK 2D Drawing Interface on top of the AGG library. This library provides high-quality drawing, with anti-aliasing and alpha compositing, while being fully compatible with the WCK renderer.

The aggdraw module can be used with PIL or the WCK library (under Tkinter or native Windows). It can also be used as a stand-alone library.

Comment: Is there a port for OS X?

Comment: Aggdraw is available on Linux, OSX, and Windows. It can be installed from PyPI with pip.