# Text not smooth from PIL ImageFont

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have created a small python script to generate a bunch of QR Codes using `pyqrcode` and using `PIL` to write the QR code value just below the QR code. The text is being written to the image using the following code:

```
def writeText(img,text):
    img = Image.open(img)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    w,h = img.size

    font = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial Black.ttf',20)
    text_w,text_h = draw.textsize(text,font)

    draw.text(((w-text_w) // 2, h-text_h-12), text,font=font)

    img.save("new.png")
```

The output text on the image is not smooth (see image) and the edges are not smooth lines. How can I achieve a high quality text on the image. Any changes in the code?

[image: Example Output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there antialiasing method for python PIL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350645/is-there-antialiasing-method-for-python-pil)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350645/is-there-antialiasing-method-for-python-pil

Comment: Could not get a proper and clear solution from the link posted.

Comment: Try to render the text on an imager bigger than your target size, then resizing it down to the original size using ANTIALIAS flag

Comment: I have tried creating at about 700x700 px and then resizing it to about 210,210 but the text is almost same.

Comment: Did you use the flag?

Comment: Yes I did. `img = img.resize((w,h),Image.ANTIALIAS)`

Comment: Try and create a bigger image. If it doesn't get better at all you know it's a problem in your code

Comment: I tried creating it at 2100x2100 px and then resizing it to 210x210 px. But the text is nearly the same. Please check if any problem in code.

Comment: post your new code then