# How to create a circular thumbnail using python pillow and overlap on background image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

avatar.jpg

[image]

back.jpg

[image]

How to synthesize two images as follows?

I Effect:

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate what *effect* do you want?

Comment: Turn a square image into a circle image

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's an example using your images. Dimensions are hardcoded in the example, but you can easily replace them with calculations. avatar.jpg and background.jpg are images in your post saved as is.

Here's a link to github repo for this example : [python_pillow_circular_thumbnail](https://github.com/shaunakv1/python_pillow_circular_thumbnail)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw

im = Image.open('avatar.jpg')
im = im.resize((120, 120));
bigsize = (im.size[0] * 3, im.size[1] * 3)
mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask) 
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + bigsize, fill=255)
mask = mask.resize(im.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.putalpha(mask)

output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
output.putalpha(mask)
output.save('output.png')

background = Image.open('back.jpg')
background.paste(im, (150, 10), im)
background.save('overlap.png')
```

**output.png:**
[image]

**overlap.png:**
[image]

Crop part of this code is borrowed form this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22336005/726239).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much~ It`s My want effect.

Comment: `ImageOps.fit` is redundant

Comment: maybe add some comments to explain what the code is doing?