# How to crop circle image from webcam OpenCV and remove background

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I am applying filter. By using OpenCv live webcam is open and it detect face and apply filter. But i want to crop the face in circle  and removed the extra background and save the image.

for example:

[image]

to this [image]

How can i implement in python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site does not serve as general problem solving portal. The community will help you to get a working solution, but you should share your code with images showing what you have done already that did not work. Read "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), "What are good topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How do I ask a good question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please identify what data you have for the location and size of the face, so we can show cropping

Comment: If you have the center coordinates you can do this [How to create a circular thumbnail using python pillow and overlap on background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42991713/how-to-create-a-circular-thumbnail-using-python-pillow-and-overlap-on-background) or this [cropping an image in a circular way, using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486297/cropping-an-image-in-a-circular-way-using-python)

Comment: See also: [How can I create a circular mask for a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865023/circular-masking-an-image-in-python-using-numpy-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to create a black mask then draw the desired region to crop out in white using `cv2.circle()`. From there we can use `cv2.bitwise_and()` with the original image and the mask. To crop the result, we can use `cv2.boundingRect()` on the mask to obtain the ROI then use Numpy slicing to extract the result. For this example I used the center point as `(335, 245)`. You can adjust the circle radius to increase or decrease the size of the circle.

[image]

Code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Create mask and draw circle onto mask
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
x,y = 335, 245
cv2.circle(mask, (x,y), 110, (255,255,255), -1)

# Bitwise-and for ROI
ROI = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

# Crop mask and turn background white
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(mask)
result = ROI[y:y+h,x:x+w]
mask = mask[y:y+h,x:x+w]
result[mask==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```