# Fitting an image into a polygon using PIL or Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a boardgame map that uses hexagon tiles (similar to a Catan board). In the background of each hex, I want an image that takes up the whole hexagon. The problem is, I don't have images that are nice hexagon shapes, so I was hoping to take a retangular image, crop it into the hex I've drawn, and use that. I am new to programming anything graphical, and have tried searching significantly but cannot seem to find a working solution. I have tried implementing the first solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circular-thumbnails-with-pil), but the image does not have a transparent background around the hexagon (its white instead).

Simply put, I need to take a square image, make it hexagonal, then display it at a set position. Advice?

Comment: Do you need hexagonal images? Can you display the board and then display your tile details over the top?

Comment: I would think some kind of parenting or layering would be a solution but I dont know. Is the map static? in that case you can just create the entire board as one image.

Answer (score 0):

When pasting one image onto another, you can supply a mask argument, that will only update the parts of the image specified - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open('test.png')

# I'm creating a random shape here
mask = Image.new('RGBA', im.size)
d = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
d.polygon(((20, 20), (20, 50), (100, 100), (100, 20)), fill='#000')

out = Image.new('RGBA', im.size)
out.paste(im, (0, 0), mask)
out.show()
```