# How to crop elliptical region from image using Python

Tags: python

I have code for rectangle cropping ,Honestly I'm beginner to python 
this code was i saw on a site

I'm using PIL library

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("lenna.png")

crop_rectangle = (50, 50, 200, 200)
cropped_im = im.crop(crop_rectangle)

cropped_im.show()
```

please help me to crop ellipse or circle region from a image 
thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate circular thumbnails with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circular-thumbnails-with-pil)

Comment: Title and the content does not match. You are not using openCV in your code.

Comment: I've removed the `OpenCV` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Cropping an image to an elliptical or circle region will produce the same results as cropping to a square, if their extents are the same. I am assuming that you also want to mask the image as well as crop?

To do this, create a blank mask PIL Image with the same extent as the original, use `PIL.ImageDraw.Draw` to draw a polygon onto the image. The mask image should now now have binary pixel values where "1" represents masked. Then simply set all values in the original image to a masked value (i.e. np.nan) where the mask pixel values equal 1 (e.g. `original_image[mask == 1] = np.nan`).