# Why does pillow load an image as a rectangle and not a circle?

Tags: python, image-processing, png, python-imaging-library, gif

I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circular-thumbnails-with-pil) for generating a circular thumbnail and ran into something unexpected. Here's my question:

For img

```py
img = Image.new('RGB', (1080, 1080), color = black)
```

For

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

mask = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L')
im = Image.open('image.png')
output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
output.putalpha(mask)
output.save('output.png')
```

Outputs as a circle (this is fine, bellow is the problem):

**output.png**

[image: First code snippet output]

But when I run this code to copy the image onto another image:

```py
    icon = Image.open('output.png', 'r')
    offset=(80,80)
    img.paste(icon, offset)
```

I end up with this:

[image: bad copy]

However if I save the image as a **gif** and use the following code then the I can get a circle:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageDraw

size = (128, 128)
mask = Image.new('L', size, 255)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
draw.ellipse((0, 0) + size, fill=0)
im = Image.open('android.png')
output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
output.paste(0, mask=mask)
output.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE)
output.save('output.gif', transparency=0)
```

**output.gif**:

[image: output.gif]

Running the same code (displayed again for convenience) using output.gif results in the correct result:

```py
    icon = Image.open('output.gif', 'r')
    offset=(80,80)
    img.paste(icon, offset)
```

[image: correct paste]

#### Can someone explain what would cause this? Is it how png is being encoded that pillow doesn't like?

Comment: What mode is `img` created with? Your [mcve] appears to be incomplete here.

Comment: I've added img at the top.

Comment: Right, transparency requires an alpha channel, and `RGB` has no alpha channel. Create an image with the `RGBA` mode.