# To improve image quality of made circular thumbnails

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, thumbnails

[How do I generate circular thumbnails with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circular-thumbnails-with-pil) shows a way how to make circular thumbnails.

Following the sample and I am using [a picture here](https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/icMTqxFzFeVY/v1/1000x-1.jpg), and here's what's generated.

[image]

The generated picture quality doesn't look very good, I want to improve it, so change the last line a bit:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

mask = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L')
im = Image.open('image.png')

output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
output.putalpha(mask)

output.save('output.png', dpi=(800,800))
```

But seems the picture quality is not improved.

What's the way to improve the picture quality after circled?

> image with solution in the answer
> [image: image with solution in the answer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a different downsampling filter, by adding, for example, `method=Image.LANCZOS` to the `.fit` call.

Comment: thank you for the help! "output = ImageOps.fit(im, mask.size, centering=(0.8, 0.8), method = Image.LANCZOS)" works!