# How to draw a progress bar with Pillow?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-imaging-library

I am currently trying to draw a progress bar, based on a calculated percentage.

However, I am not able to display it in the right format.

I orientated myself on another answer from this site here ([How do you make a progress bar and put it on an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66886200/how-do-you-make-a-progress-bar-and-put-it-on-an-image) & [Is it possible to add a blue bar using PIL or Pillow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520629/is-it-possible-to-add-a-blue-bar-using-pil-or-pillow))

But either the case is that the progress bar is too long and the `width` restriction does not work or the bar shows no progress.

**Example 1:**

```py
async def rank(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    member = ctx.author

    data = await database.find_user(collection_user, ctx.guild.id, ctx.author.id)
    already_earned = data["exp"]

    to_reach= ((50 * (data['lvl'] ** 2)) + (50 * (data['lvl'] - 1)))
    
    percentage = ((data["exp"] / next_level_xp ) * 100) # Get the percentage

    ## Rank card
    img = Image.open("leveling/rank.png")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    font = ImageFont.truetype("settings/myfont.otf", 35)
    font1 = ImageFont.truetype("settings/myfont.otf", 24)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(str(ctx.author.avatar)) as response:
            image = await response.read()
    icon = Image.open(BytesIO(image)).convert("RGBA")
    img.paste(icon.resize((156, 156)), (50, 60))

    # Some text drawn, this works

    ### From StackOverflow ###
    def drawProgressBar(d, x, y, w, h, progress, bg=(129, 66, 97), fg=(211,211,211)):
        # draw background
        draw.ellipse((x+w, y, x+h+w, y+h), fill=bg)
        draw.ellipse((x, y, x+h, y+h), fill=bg)
        draw.rectangle((x+(h/2), y, x+w+(h/2), y+h), fill=bg, width=10)

        # draw progress bar
        progress = ((already_earned / to_reach ) * 100)
        w *= progress 
        draw.ellipse((x+w, y, x+h+w, y+h),fill=fg)
        draw.ellipse((x, y, x+h, y+h),fill=fg)
        draw.rectangle((x+(h/2), y, x+w+(h/2), y+h),fill=fg, width=10)

        return d

    drawProgressBar(img, 10, 10, 100, 25, 0.5)
    ### From StackOverflow ###

    img.save('leveling/infoimg2.png') # Save it and send it out
```

**This looks like this:**
[image]

**Second example:**

```py
async def rank(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):

    member = ctx.author

    data = await database.find_user(collection_user, ctx.guild.id, ctx.author.id)
    already_earned = data["exp"]

    to_reach = ((50 * (data['lvl'] ** 2)) + (50 * (data['lvl'] - 1)))
    
    percentage = ((already_earned / to_reach) * 100) # Get the percentage 

    img = Image.open("leveling/rank.png")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    ### From StackOverflow ###
    color=(129, 66, 97)
    x, y, diam = percentage, 8, 34
    draw.ellipse([x,y,x+diam,y+diam], fill=color)
    ImageDraw.floodfill(img, xy=(14,24), value=color, thresh=40)
    ### From StackOverflow ###

    font = ImageFont.truetype("settings/myfont.otf", 35)
    font1 = ImageFont.truetype("settings/myfont.otf", 24)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(str(ctx.author.avatar)) as response:
            image = await response.read()
    icon = Image.open(BytesIO(image)).convert("RGBA")
    img.paste(icon.resize((156, 156)), (50, 60))
    # Draw some other text here, this works though
    img.save('leveling/infoimg2.png') # Save the file and output it
```

**Which looks like this:**
[image]

Both results do not match the pictures shown in the answers and questions.

Is somebody able to tell me where I went wrong?
I also tried to increase `x` in the second example or set `img = Image.open("pic.png").format('RGB')` but nothing seems to work. The progress bar is either too long or too short.

I tried to achieve that my progress bar is restricted to some size, always matches 100% and that my defined `progress` will adapt to it.

Comment: Please click [edit] and make sure your code is complete and runnable. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I edited my text for more information.

Comment: FYI just for visual comparison and inspiration, here are implementations using standard libraries, tqdm, alive-progress, etc. [Python Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160699/python-progress-bar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your code was that the background and progress bar sections were of the same color, and as such, you couldn't see it. This can be fixed by coloring them differently.

The line `progress = ((already_earned / to_reach ) * 100)` also sets `progress` to a percentage `[0, 100]`. You then multiply `width` by this. For the input of `100`, a fill amount of 50% for example makes the ellipse go `5000` pixels - way off the screen and overwriting everything that was already drawn there.

```py
@client.command(name='rank')
async def rank(ctx, progress: float):

    # Open the image and do stuff
    # I tested this with a blank 800x400 RGBA

    def new_bar(x, y, width, height, progress, bg=(129, 66, 97), fg=(211,211,211), fg2=(15,15,15)):
        # Draw the background
        draw.rectangle((x+(height/2), y, x+width+(height/2), y+height), fill=fg2, width=10)
        draw.ellipse((x+width, y, x+height+width, y+height), fill=fg2)
        draw.ellipse((x, y, x+height, y+height), fill=fg2)
        width = int(width*progress)
        # Draw the part of the progress bar that is actually filled
        draw.rectangle((x+(height/2), y, x+width+(height/2), y+height), fill=fg, width=10)
        draw.ellipse((x+width, y, x+height+width, y+height), fill=fg)
        draw.ellipse((x, y, x+height, y+height), fill=fg)

    new_bar(10, 10, 100, 25, progress)


    # send
```

---

Example:

`progress = 0.25`
[image]

`progress = 0.9`
[image]

---

As to the second code snippet, it's using [`floodfill()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html?highlight=floodfill#PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill) incorrectly. `thresh` is the "maximum tolerable difference of a pixel value from the ‘background’ in order for it to be replaced." This means that the floodfill does literally nothing, and you only drew the ellipse (and not the part of the progress bar that goes before it).

```py
    # this draws a circle with bounding box `x,y` and `x+diam,y+diam`
    # note that `x` is dependent on the progress value: higher progress means larger x, which means the circle is drawn more to the right
    draw.ellipse([x,y, x+diam,y+diam], fill=color)
    # If you look at the post where the code was given, you can see the error.
    # In that post, the entirety of the progress bar already exists, and is a very different color (allowing the use of the threshold value).
    # In this code, no progress bar exists yet, meaning everything else is just one solid color, and then the floodfill cannot do anything.
    # Also, xy is specified as arbitrary coordinates, which you would need to change to fit your bar.
    # This does nothing.
    ImageDraw.floodfill(img, xy=(14,24), value=color, thresh=40)
```

If you want to fix this, you need to fill in the color to the left of the progress bar. The first function above already does this. If you want, you can remove the first 3 lines to avoid drawing a background, producing the same results.

Comment: FYI that choice of colors (ellipse on dark-grey bar on black background) is bad for contrast, accessibility.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, that was pretty helpful. Drawing the black bar and the grey works. However, I am still encountering some problems on this matter: My percentage says I am at `0.97` and the `width = int(width*progress)` calculates it as `97` so the bar is filled at nearly 1 percent. How would I come across this, e.g. make the bar longer in general and avoid calculation errors like this?

Comment: Maybe I also need to add this: I removed `progress: float` and just said `new_bar(10, 10, 100, 25)` - If that is causing I would have to find a way around to also use `float` as I do not want to make it a requirement for the command.

Comment: It's fine, that was just a placeholder. The `progress` that you passed to the function that I wrote is in the range `[0, 1]`, where 1 means fully filled and 0 means empty. So you have to divide by 100. If you wanted to say 0.97%, you would have to pass the value `0.0097`. I wouldn't say it's the bar because it rounds to the nearest pixel, but you can increase the size if you wanted.

Comment: @EricJin Thanks for the explanation, makes sense to reform the progress in this case. Very useful answer!