# How to use python code to crop a serial circle region on a single image

Tags: python, image, pixel, segment

Please take a look at the Figure [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1fpa.jpg)

The original image is 90x90 pixels

how to crop a 10x10 pixels circle from top left to bottom right and save each image with name 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg ... to 90.jpg respectively?

So that I can get 90 circle images.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate circular thumbnails with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circular-thumbnails-with-pil)

Comment: It's a similar question. However in that post, the cropped position is in the center. And I tried to shift the centering to (0.1, 0.1) the cropped area is still too close to center.  I even change the thumbnail size but the cropped portion is too big. What I need is to crop 10 pixels in diameter so that I can have 90  cropped circle images from a single 90 by 90 pixels image. Thank you