# Pillow chop image, keep transparency

Tags: python, image, resize, python-imaging-library

I was trying to resize an image to a circular shape, but if i run the code, the transparency of the image is gone.

```py
from PIL import Image,ImageOps

pb = Image.open('pb_image')

bigsize = (pb.size[0] * 3, pb.size[1] * 3)

mask = Image.new('L', bigsize, 0)

mask = mask.resize(pb.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
pb.putalpha(mask)

circled = ImageOps.fit(pb, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))
circled.putalpha(mask)

circled.show()
```

This is my code (pb is a loaded image), but either the image is not resized at all,
the image is resized but the transparent places are black
or the image is completely transparent.
I dont know how to fix this im new to pillow.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post to make it actually runnable - that means putting back the `import` statements you have removed for some reason, and including your input and actual output image (or reasonable representation of them) and expected output image (or a reasonable mock-up).

Answer (score 0):

from [How do I generate circular thumbnails with PIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890051/how-do-i-generate-circular-thumbnails-with-pil)

using mask.png :

[image]

code:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageOps

image = 'pb.png'


pb = Image.open(image)

mask = Image.open('mask.png').convert('L') 

mask = mask.resize(pb.size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

circled = ImageOps.fit(pb, mask.size, centering=(0.5, 0.5))

circled.putalpha(mask)

circled.show()

circled.save('out.png')
```